How exclude Hangfire requests from tracing information?
I use OpenTelemetry to collect tracing and to send them to the AWS X-Ray. And I want to exlude traces related to Hangfire requests, because it creates in the AWS X-Ray Trace Map new sequence Client -> DB and collect 80-100 requests per minute. Correct sequence still exists and looks like Client -> App -> DB. My code for setting OTel:
        Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
            .AddXRayTraceId()
            .AddAWSInstrumentation()
            .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
            .AddHangfireInstrumentation()
            .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
            .AddEntityFrameworkCoreInstrumentation()
            .AddNpgsql()
            .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder
                .CreateDefault()
                .AddService(otelOptions.ServiceName)
                .AddDetector(new AWSEC2ResourceDetector())
                .AddTelemetrySdk())
            .AddSource(otelOptions.ServiceName)
            .AddOtlpExporter(opts =>
            {
                opts.Endpoint = new Uri(otelOptions.Endpoint);
            })
            .Build();


So how I can exclude Hangfire requests from tracing information?
I tried to add filters using EntityFrameworkInstrumentationOptions, maybe I was wrong somewhere, but it didn't work. I check .AddHangfireInstrumentation() method and tried to work with HangfireInstrumentationOptions, but still no result.

The solution is not to use .UseNpgsql(), because it collects all the requests to the DB :) You can just use .AddEntityFrameworkCoreInstrumentation().

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
